# URL prompting download instead of reading page

Tags: browser, url

I have a weird error.

On my phone, a URL works, displaying the web page within. On my laptop (Thinkpad Ubuntu 18.04) whether on Firefox or Chromium, the URL prompts the download of the file, saying it's a deb file.

What could be going wrong?

Also, curling the URL returns the html file just fine.

Cleared cache etc, and restarted the machine, but no difference.

Comment: URL is innovationbound.com/services (It's just a static site on S3 with Cloudfront in front). Previously I had a folder called services as well, but no longer.

Comment: When I try that URL, it redirects to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html. Is that supposed to happen? Also please [edit] your post to add details.

Comment: @wjandrea Holy crap! Thanks for the heads up. I had a lambda@edge function I was editing for redirects and it took over the whole site.